# How to fix 'You don't have permission to open the application' on Mac?

Tags: macos, mac, zsh, chmod

I get the following error when I try to open the app on the mac.

[image]

I tried using the following solutions:

[image]

Also here is the behavior when I use the keyboard shortcut:

[image]

Comment: Use an admin account.  If you don’t have one, you’ll have to ask an admin.

Comment: @Tetsujin i am using admin account.

Comment: Unless there are different rules in different regions, you can’t put the app name in angle brackets, use double quotes, and skip the backslash before the space. But, before trying to make the folder executable (remember, apps are just folders), why don’t you show the permissions on the folder AND its contents, all the way down. Something else is wrong, maybe the whole app is corrupted, so maybe try downloading it again?

Comment: @CharlesKenyon updated question.

Answer (score 0):

Select the app, then press `cmd`+`I` and at the bottom, where it says `Sharing & Permissions` select your name and do `Read & Write`

Comment: the default value is as follows